# SSH: Torch-Lua Script Unexpectedly Stops

Tags: command-line, ssh, lua, scripting

I'm trying to run a Torch-Lua script on the **luajit** interpreter by using **SSH** on a remote (Ubuntu 14.04) machine. It runs only for two iterations and displays all the outputs accordingly, but, as soon as the third iteration is going to complete, due to some unexpected reason, it seems to stop all by itself and I am returned to the **terminal** of the remote machine.

It doesn't display any standard OS messages, like the 'luajit' process being killed or being terminated with a signal. I used 'top' to check if it is running in the background but that is not the case. Neither it is the case that the remote machine is turning off, nor am I losing connection because I stay connected to the remote machine through SSH. And certainly, the script shouldn't have any issues as the exact same script runs till completion in my local machine. I would also like to mention that I have **sudo**-er permissions on the remote machine as well.

I am posting this because I have tried the same on two different, independent remote machines and it behaves in the same way. Can someone please help me by sharing what might be the cause(s) behind the "mysterious" way this script/machine might be behaving and possible solution(s) which I could try?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The following is the output which I receive on the terminal every time I run the same script:

```
==> the main loop   
==> online epoch # 1 [batchSize = 128]  
 [==================== 15/15 ==================>]  Tot: 46s400ms | Step: 3s314ms
Train accuracy: 4.90 %   time: 50.33 s  
==> testing 
Test accuracy: 1.50 %= 8 time: 3.05 s====>......]  ETA: 387ms | Step: 3ms       
==> online epoch # 2 [batchSize = 128]  
 [==================== 15/15 ==================>]  Tot: 49s439ms | Step: 3s531ms
Train accuracy: 5.05 %   time: 50.44 s  
==> testing 
Test accuracy: 1.50 %= 8 time: 2.92 s====>......]  ETA: 369ms | Step: 2ms       
==> online epoch # 3 [batchSize = 128]  
 [==================== 15/15 ==================>]  Tot: 50s620ms | Step: 3s615ms
Train accuracy: 5.00 %   time: 51.38 s  
user-name@my-remote-machine:~/path/to/script$
```

(As you can see from the output, the script is essentially a training-testing procedure for a conv-net.)

Comment: What *exactly* do you see? What is the return code of the process? Does the remote machine have execution limits on time for a single process?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I have included what I see in the **EDIT** to the question; As you can see, I can't see any return code of the process which makes it strange. And the remote machine is a well equipped machine in terms of CPU, memory and GPU-support. Using 'top', I can see that some other processes of **ipython** have been running for few days on the same machine without any issues I guess.

Comment: What does `echo "ret: $?"` say at that prompt right after it exits? What's the script itself look like? If you add debugging statements to right after that last message prints to where the loop restarts do they print out?

Comment: @EtanReisner, the above command displays `ret: 141` at the prompt. The script is slightly large to share here but it is essentially structured by taking help from [this tutorial](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/tree/master/2_supervised), with some modifications to adapt to my model. I'm manually trying to debug it now (using print statements as you suggested) and will update them here soon.

Comment: `141` is an error and some quick googling suggests that it might be a `SIGPIPE`. Is there something in your script/etc. that could be hitting a pipe error?

Comment: Yeah, @EtanReisner, I just googled it and found the same, though I'm unfamiliar with this error. In general, by using what type of functions in the script could one hit this error?

Comment: `SIGPIPE`s happen when something tries to write to a pipe that's been closed as far as I know. You'll need to figure out what in your program could be writing to a pipe. Are you writing output somewhere? Does it always happen at the same time into the program's processing?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I resolved my issue and have explained how I got it woking in the answer to this question. And yes, my script was writing output in the form of training and testing logs, while continuing processing the data in the next epoch. Since *gnuplot* was reading the same logs to display the corresponding plots, I guess that somehow that was causing this `SIGPIPE` error which was terminating the execution of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking over and debugging, I found the issue with my script and resolved it.

Neither the SSH nor the system's configuration was terminating the script's execution. The problem was a little one with my script. Since the remote-machine that I was connecting to was not accessible as a standard desktop (by which I mean that it didn't have any desktop environment like GNOME), so I couldn't do '**ssh -x**' to the machine. All the interactions with the machine could be done just with the command line.

So, there was one feature of "**live plot**" in my script which basically took the training/testing logs, being actively created by the script after each epoch, and *displayed* training/testing accuracy-versus-epoch plot (using '*gnuplot*'). In my original script (which ran on my CPU-only, desktop-environment-enabled machine), it was enabled. Since I was initially using the same script on my remote machine, the same enabling was causing this strange problem in my case. After I disabled it, I was able to get the epochs running and the training-testing procedure working correctly, as I expected it to. In my script, it was just a flag, which I had to set to true/false, in order to enable/disable this "live plot" feature (similar to the way it is done in [this tutorial](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/tree/master/2_supervised)).